# Terraform with AWS provider unable to create CodeBuild

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

I am trying to create a AWS CodeBuild using Terraform.

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "cicd_codebuild" {
  name          = "cicd-${var.profile}-build"
  description   = "cicd ${var.profile} CodeBuild"
  service_role  = "${aws_iam_role.cicd_role.arn}"

  source {
    type = "GITHUB_ENTERPRISE"
    location = "https://git.xxx.com/yyy/zzz.git"
    git_clone_depth = 0
    buildspec = "NO_SOURCE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-1.0"
    type                        = "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
  }
}
```

Upon `terraform apply` I get error:

```
Error: aws_codebuild_project.cicd_codebuild: expected environment.0.type to be one of [LINUX_CONTAINER LINUX_GPU_CONTAINER WINDOWS_CONTAINER ARM_CONTAINER], got WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER
```

And when I change value of `environment.0.type = "WINDOWS_CONTAINER"` I get below error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error occurred:
        * aws_codebuild_project.cicd_codebuild: 1 error occurred:
        * aws_codebuild_project.cicd_codebuild: Error creating CodeBuild project: InvalidInputException: The environment type WINDOWS_CONTAINER is deprecated for new projects or existing project environment updates. Please consider using Windows Server 2019 instead.
```

I found on GitHub that [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16163) issue has been addressed in next versions. So, I know upgrading provider version can solve this but do we have any workaround to fix this issue in same version of Terraform and Provider.

**Thanks.**

Comment: TF 0.11 is very,  very old. Any reason why not to use something modern?

Comment: Due to other dependencies and until we fully migrate to newer version we can't right TF files in higher version so for time being need to write it in 0.11 itself.

Comment: Does that first error happen at plan or apply time?

Comment: It happens at the time of apply. In plan I see no error, rather it says 1 to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform has plan time validation on many resource parameters that allows for catching where you are passing an invalid parameter before you get to the point of trying to apply it.

Normally this is beneficial but if you are not able to keep up to date with the provider versions it means that that list of allowed values can get out of date with what is actually allowed by the backing service the provider is talking to.

In this specific case [a pull request added the `WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER` as a plan time validation option](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/commit/1901f9ad85e57b5a15de6317267d88c6b92d0823) after [AWS added that functionality in July 2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/history.html).

Unfortunately for you, this work was merged and released as part of the [v3.20.0 release of the AWS provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.2.0) and [the v3 releases only support Terraform 0.12 and up](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#300-july-31-2020):

> BREAKING CHANGES
>
> - provider: New versions of the provider can only be automatically installed on Terraform 0.12 and later (#14143)

If you want to be able to use Windows containers in CodeBuild you either need to upgrade to a more recent version of Terraform and the AWS provider or you need to use a different tool for creating the CodeBuild project.

One potential workaround here is to use [CloudFormation to create the CodeBuild project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-project.html) which you could run via Terraform using the [`aws_cloudformation_stack` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack).

Comment: I opted for creating CodeBuild using CFN via Terraform and working fine. As if now its good for my problem. Thanks @ydaetskcoR